# Eixo dinâmico - DAX

Tags: gráfico, powerbi, dax

Eu estou montando uma dashboard, que possui uma **Tabela** com os dados com o resumo de uma produção de uma empresa (Tabela1), e outro visual: um **Gráfico de linhas** com os dados com o acompanhamento da produção por data (Tabela2).

Dashboard:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dados da tabela resumo de produção (Tabela1):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dados da tabela acompanhamento de produção (Tabela2):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou precisando que quando o usuário interagir com o visual Tabela, navegando entre as linhas de produção, o gráfico de linhas vá mudando de acordo com a interação do usuário. entre as colunas, mas precisamente a de colunas de Data.

O que já tentei:
Criei uma **medida** na qual tinha como código:

```
Medida = IF(SELECTEDVALUE(Tabela1[LINHA])= "Agendamento", SELECTCOLUMNS(Tabela2,"Agendamento",Tabela2[Agendamento-Data]))
```

Mas não retorna a coluna desejável. E também já tentei criar uma coluna nessa mesma condição, sem sucesso também.

Comment: UP-UP-UP-UP-UP-UP